# How to set my resolution to 7680x4320 (8x)?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

My current resolution in my updated (up to date) Nvidia GeForce 620 GT is 3840x2160 (4x), but I want to set my resolution to 7680x4320 (8x), but 3840x2160 is the highest and maximum I can do in my current Nvidia GeForce version. Is there another special way, tactic, strategy, hack or registry modification to set this very high resolution? I am asking this, because I am gamer and I like to play games in super HD resolution. They look pretty nice and excellent in super HD resolutions, and it thrills me so much. So much details and precision and sharpening.

Comment: per the manufacturer specs for your card, your max res is 2560x1600. Its  nice that GeForce upgrades have allowed you to acheive 4K res, but pushing it to almost 4x the manufacture spec is asking a lot. http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-620/specifications

Comment: How does your card even handle that with decent settings? I use a 980TI, and my old 660 only really did up to 1440p

Comment: If you're wanting to do it with a single monitor, I don't think one has been created, yet, with that resolution.  You could do multiple monitors, as in a 2x2 array, which people like to say is a way of achieving higher resolution.

Comment: I have already thought about making 2x2 array, but the problem is that I don't know how to do that, and I have only one monitor, but not four, and I don't have enough money to buy another three monitors, even not one :(, but thank you for your suggestions in your comments.

Comment: 8K gaming with a GT 620? Not effing likely. ;) Even at 4K, you’d probably have low FPS in Solitaire. So, sorry, but I’m calling BS on this one.

Comment: I have just checked my Nvidia "System Information" and in "Display" tab it says "GeForce GT 620", but I succeeded to set my resolution to 3840x2160 in Dynamic Super Resolution". Also this post got negative score and I don't know why! :(

Comment: @user611702 Desktop resolution and resolution in the games you play are usually not the same. What games are you playing? Full screen a game and then look at the video settings ingame and check the resolution. I bet they are NOT 3840x2160. Regardless, the card you have cannot handle anything higher and they don't make single monitors that are above 5k (5120 x 2880) for consumers yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'maximum' resolution you can do with [DSR seems to be linked to your maximum resolution](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2332706/gtx-980-dsr-technology.html), and 4x that of whatever your screen is.

That said, there's no way a 620 can run 4k + good/ultra settings. Practically, a better card might be on the cards, and I'm baffled to how this even works. Your graphics card *isn't* nearly anywhere powerful enough for high quality 4k gaming. Its a little like trying to race the indy 500 with a yak drawn sled.

Comment: My graphics card is not "strong" enough to play games with nice effects, like lighting, shadows, particles and so on with high FPS, but if I turn all effects OFF, I have 30 FPS in HD, which is playable. Nice effects in low resolution is lame. I prefer to play in very high resolution instead of game effects.